# How do I disable shortcut menus for the form but enable shortcut menus for textboxes on the form?

Tags: ms-access

In access, I have a (continuous) form with textboxes on it. For these textboxes, I have created shortcut menus and assigned these to the textboxes (through *Shortcut Menu Bar* property).

In order for these shortcut menus to popup on a right mouse click on the textboxes, I need the form to have the *Shortcut Menu* property to be yes.

Yet, setting this *Shortcut Menu* property to yes *also* opens a (default) shortcut menu when I right click on the form. I don't want this default shortcut menu to pop up.

So, how can I have the shortcut menu for the textboxes but disable them for the form hosting the textboxes?

Comment: Have you seen the option to make [custom shortcut menus](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194247.aspx)? You can make a blank shortcut menu for the form then make your own shortcut menu and assign that to a textbox.

Comment: @Brad I have seen this article but I still struggle to have *no* shortcut menu whatsoever when I right click on the area on the form that is not occupied by the textbox. I probably don't understand what you mean by "blank shortcut menu"

Comment: `CommandBars.Add("BlankShortcutMenu", msoBar, False, True)` > Set Forms `Shortcut Menu Bar` to `BlankShortcutMenu` > http://imgur.com/LNOXXmw Not amazing but not terrible.