# Enabling Shortcut Menu only on a specific Form control (TextBox)

Tags: ms-access, vba

This is closely related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29984940/how-do-i-disable-shortcut-menus-for-the-form-but-enable-shortcut-menus-for-textb), which hasn't got an answer posted.

I have a Form where I would like to have the Shortcut Menu (the one that pops up with right click) enabled only when clicked inside a TextBox on that Form (disabled every where else). The problem is that it seems like that option is only global to the entire Form.

Having the Form's ShortcutMenu set to False, I can set it to True in a TextBox's "On Enter" event using "ShortcutMenu = True", making the right click do nothing until the TextBox is entered. The problem with this is that when a user enters the TextBox, if he right clicks anywhere else in the form, the right click menu will appear, which is not as I intend.

Disabling the ShortcutMenu by using "ShortcutMenu = False" in the "On Exit" event of the same TextBox works but only if the user clicks on another control, not before, which doesn't solve the problem.

Is there anyway to run "ShortcutMenu = False" before the right click action on someplace is executed? (After entering the TextBox). Something like an "the mouse moved away from this control" event?

Comment: Not sure, but could you use the Form  'MouseMove' event to determine if over that box, or possibly the MouseDown event or GotFocus event?

Comment: Using GotFocus on the TextBox results in a similar behavior for enabling Shortcut Menus to what I used above. I could see MouseMove working, but I would have to know the exact position, in Twips of the TextBox so I could do "If pointer outside box position then..." But I'm not proficient enough to do that. Also, that will keep executing "ShortcutMenu = False" which flickers Form content.

Comment: There are approximately 1440 twips to a inch. So you could immediately check If X >= Me.txtA,Left * 1440 and X <=  (Me.txtLeft + Me.txtA.Width) * 1440 And Y >= Me.txtA.Top * 1440 and  Y <= (Me.txtA.top + me.txtA.Height) * 1440 Then... else exit sub...  (don't remember if X & Y or Y & X)

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn : thanks for the comment, but O.Gungor's posted solution works and I'm pressed for time, can't explore your idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can accomplish this by creating 2 customized shortcut menus on the fly. one will basically be a dummy shortcut menu for the entire form, with no controls in it, the other will be the one you want to appear on your actual control. I have these set to temporary. you will need to adjust the custom controls to what you want displayed when they right-click.

```
Private Const CntrlShortcutMenu As String = "CntrlShortCutMenu"
Private Const FormShortcutMenu As String = "FormShortCutMenu"

Private Sub Form_Load()
 Call CreateControlShortcutMenu("txtvalue1")
 Call CreateDummyShortcutMenuonForm
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Unload(Cancel As Integer)
 DeleteShortCutMenu (CntrlShortcutMenu)
 DeleteShortCutMenu (FormShortcutMenu)
End Sub

Private Sub CreateDummyShortcutMenuonForm()
    Call DeleteShortCutMenu(FormShortcutMenu)
    Call CommandBars.Add(FormShortcutMenu, 5, False, True)
    Me.ShortcutMenuBar = FormShortcutMenu
End Sub

Private Sub DeleteShortCutMenu(MenuName As String)
  On Error Resume Next
  CommandBars(MenuName).Delete
End Sub

Private Sub CreateControlShortcutMenu(CntrlName As String)

On Error GoTo errhandler

    Dim cmdShortcutMenu As Object 'Office.CommandBar

    Call DeleteShortCutMenu(CntrlShortcutMenu)

    Set cmdShortcutMenu = CommandBars.Add(CntrlShortcutMenu, 5, False, True)

        With cmdShortcutMenu

             With .Controls.Add(Type:=10)
                .Caption = "Text Editing"
                .Controls.Add Type:=1, Id:=19   'Copy
                .Controls.Add Type:=1, Id:=22   'Paste
                .Controls.Add Type:=1, Id:=2941 'Select All
             End With

             With .Controls.Add(Type:=10)
                .Caption = "Filter"
                .Controls.Add Type:=1, Id:=210  'Sort Ascending
                .Controls.Add Type:=1, Id:=211  'Sort Descending
                .Controls.Add Type:=1, Id:=640  'Filter By Selection
                .Controls.Add Type:=1, Id:=3017 'Filter Excluding Selection
                .Controls.Add Type:=2, Id:=2863 'Filter For
                .Controls.Add Type:=1, Id:=605  'Remove Filter/Sort
             End With

        End With

        Me.Controls(CntrlName).ShortcutMenuBar = CntrlShortcutMenu

ExitSub:
    Set cmdShortcutMenu = Nothing
    Exit Sub
errhandler:
    Debug.Print "CreateControlShortcutMenu", Err.Description
    Resume ExitSub
End Sub
```

Comment: Btw, if anyone wants all the codes (IDs) for shortcut menus and other detailed info, check [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=6627) .